# How to upload images with the Dashboard and know the image URL using cloudinary?

Tags: image, file-upload, cloudinary

**Goal:** My goal ist to upload images and a) keep the original name and b) know the exact URL path.

I set the Upload preset to:

Overwrite: true
Use filename or externally defined public ID: true
Unique filename: false
Delivery type: upload
Access mode: public

When I upload images using the **Dashboard Media Library** my images keep the original filename (which is great) but cloudinary adds a unique ID  "v1585290075" into the URL.

https:// strong textres.cloudinary.com/xxxxx/image/upload/ => v1585290075 <= /2020-03-27-ee-apps/xxxxxxx.png

This unique ID prevents me from knowing the exact URL.

**Question:** How can I upload images and avoid getting the unique ID in the URL??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Unique ID you're referring to is a version component that you can utilize to bust the CDN's cache (see [here](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202520912-What-are-image-versions-)). It is not mandatory and you can safely remove it and the images will still show.